# How to replace the default wallpapers in android

Tags: android, wallpaper, launcher

We're building a custom system which is running on android.

In my app I need to replace the default wallpapers images and load our own custom images.How to do that?

Do I need to replace the images from the file system and recompile the android? If I need to recompile the source then is there any way to do that with out compiling the android source?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set wallpaper using [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html).
To change example wallpapers in Home application you must change it's resources and recompile it.